# Do preconditions ALWAYS have to be checked?

Tags: design-by-contract

These days I'm used to checking every single precondition for every function since I got the habit from an OS programming course back at uni.

On the other hand, at the software engineering course we were taught that a common precondition should only be checked once, so for example, if a function is delegating to another function, the first function should check them but checking them again in the second one is redundant.

I do see the redundancy point, but I certainly feel it's safer to always check them, plus you don't have to keep track of where they were checked previously.

What's the best practice here?

Comment: *On the other hand, at the software engineering course we were taught that a common precondition should only be checked once* I guess the best case were if one had only immutable data structures and one could tag them with _"this passed constraint 'foo'"_ (in a sense, that's what instances are: bunches of constraints) and thus there would be no need check for foo-nosity again in a procedure caller later, neither in pre or nor postconditions. And then you could have to tools to "pull preconditions" up the call tree so that they can be checked early and thus we can fail early..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have seen no "hard and fast" rule on how to check preconditions, but I generally treat it like method documentation.  If it is publicly scoped, I assert that the preconditions are met.  The logic behind this would be that the scope dictates that you are expecting consumption on a broader scale and with less influence.

Personally, the effort to put assertions around private methods is something I reserve for "mission critical" methods, which would basically be ones that either perform a critical task, are subject to external compliance requirements, or are non-recoverable in the event of an exception.  These are largely "judgment calls".

The time saved can be reinvested in thorough unit and integration test enhancement to try and flush out these issues and puts the tooling in place to help enforce the quality of the input assertions as it would be consumed by a client, whether it is a class in your control or not.

Answer (score 5):

I think it depends on how the team is organized: check inputs which come from outside your team.

- Check inputs from end-users
- Check inputs from software components written by other teams
- Trust inputs received from within your own component / within your own team.

The reason for this is for support and maintenance (i.e. bug-fixing): when there's a bug report, you want to be able as quickly as possible to know which component is at fault, i.e. which team to assign the bug to.

Comment: I think that makes a lot of sense.  It very much depends on who you are coding for.

Comment: // , You should still *document* preconditions or inputs that are received from within your own component / within your own team, though.  I just ran into a few of those undocumented, and it's been hairy.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, it depends on your encapsulation.
If the inner function is private then you can be pretty sure that its preconditions are set.

Guess it's all about the Law of Demeter, talk only to your friends and so on.

As a basis for best practise, if the call is public, you should check your inputs.

Comment: Great answer! I was looking for someone to say something about the Law of Demeter. Which is exactly why in Java assertions are only used to check preconditions in private methods etc

Answer (score 4):

> if a function is delegating to another
>   function, the first function should
>   check them but checking them again in
>   the second one is redundant.

What if you change the way those functions call each other? Or you introduce new validation requirements in the second function, that the first one delegates to? I'd say it's safer to always check them.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought and thus asked the question. Still I'm not so sure now after seeing the other answers. So far I think joseph ferris' approach makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Pin It's a question of balance. Upon refactoring, some private functions may be moved and have their dependencies changed, in which case it's better not to check their preconditions, as those would be handled by the public methods that call them. On the other hand, formerly private methods may become public during, say, an API extending phase, so they would need their preconditions checked.

Answer (score 4):

I've made the habit of distinguishing between *checking* and *asserting* the preconditions, depending (as people pointed out in the comments) on whether a call comes from the outside (unchecked exception, may happen) or the inside (assert, shouldn't happen).

Ideally, the production system won't have the penalty of the asserts, and you could even use a Design By Contract(TM)-like mechanism to discharge the assertions statically.

Comment: I agree. I believe that asserting preconditions should be done even in private methods (assuming it not affect performance) because it helps avoid bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I think that best practice is to do these checks only if they're going to fail some day.  If will help when you do the following.

**Debugging**

There's no point to check them when several private functions in one module, which has a single maintainer, exchange data.  Of course, there are exceptions, especially if your language doesn't have a static type system, or your data are "[stringly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2444303#2444303)".

However, if you expose public API, one day, someone will fail your precondition.  The further is the person that maintains the calling module from you (in organizational structure and in physical location), the more likely it will happen.  And when it happens, a clear statement of precondition failure, with a specification where it happened, may save hours of debugging.  [The Law of Leaky Abstractions](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) is still true...

**QA**

Precondition failure helps QA to debug their tests.  If a unit-test for a module causes the module to yield precondition failure, it means that the test is incorrect, not your code.  (Or, that your precondition check is incorrect, but that's less likely).

If one of the means to perform QA is **static analysis**, then precondition checks, if they have a specific notation (for example, only these checks use `assert_precondition` macro), will also help.  In static analysis it's very important to distinguish incorrect input and source code errors.

**Documentation**

If you don't have much time to create documentation, you may make your code aid the text that accompanies it.  Clear and visible precondition checks, which are perceived separate from the rest of the implementation, "document" possible inputs to some extent.  (Another way to document your code this way is writing unit tests).

Answer (score 2):

As with everything, evaluate your requirements to find the best solution for each situation.

When preconditions are easier to check ("pointer isn't null"), you might as well do that often. Preconditions which are hard to check ("points to a valid null-terminated string") or are expensive in time, memory, or other resources may be handled a different way.  Use the [Pareto principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) and gather the low-hanging fruit.

```
// C, C++:
void example(char const* s) {
  // precondition: s points to a valid null-terminated string
  assert(s); // tests that s is non-null, which is required for it to point to
  // a valid null-terminated string.  the real test is nearly impossible from
  // within this function
}
```

Guaranteeing preconditions is the responsibility of the *caller*.  Because of this, several languages offer an "assert" construct that can optionally be skipped (e.g. defining NDEBUG for C/C++, command-line switch for Python) so that you can more extensively test preconditions in special builds without impacting final performance.  However, how to use assert can be a heated debate—again, figure out your requirements and be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

It is a little bit old question, but no, preconditions do not have to be checked every time. It really depends.

For example, what if you have binary search over vector. Precondition is sorted vector. Now, if you check every time if vector is sorted this takes a linear time (for each vector), so it is not efficient. Client must be aware of precondition and be sure to meet it.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to always check them.

Comment: *Your* best practice is to always check them.  ;-)